# Restoring the superuser account on the postgres server

Tags: postgresql, role

I have a complete curious situation with a postgres dbms. I have installed the database and due to a misconfiguration of my installation scripts I made the superuser role to be a regular user. Now I have a completeley fresh installation of postgres with only the template database and a single user 'postgres' that can do pretty much nothing. How can I make postgres user superuser again?

I tried to reinstall the server under ubuntu 12.04 with `aptitude reinstall postgresql-9.1` but the role seems to be unaffected. Most probably because the reinstallation does not affect the files where the roles are recorded.

Comment: reinstalling `postgresql-common` does not help either :(

Comment: had to `apt-get --purge remove postgresql-9.1` to drop the config files. After the reinstallation the postgres became superuser again. I wonder which config option makes the postgres user to be a superuser

Comment: **WARNING** to other readers: Running the command given in the comment above command may (depending on the exact PostgreSQL packages in use) **UNRECOVERABLY DELETE YOUR DATABASE**. Do not run it on a system with data you care about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Superuser rights aren't in any config file, they're part of the `pg_catalog.pg_authid` database table, which is shared between all databases in a PostgreSQL install.

You  need to stop the PostgreSQL server, then restart it in *single user mode*, where it's always running as superuser.

There, you can `ALTER USER myuser SUPERUSER` to grant superuser rights. Exit single user mode, and start the server back up.

The exact details are a little distro and version dependent, but something like:

```
service postgresql stop
sudo -u postgres postgres --single /var/lib/pgsql/9.1/main/data

ALTER USER postgres SUPERUSER;

(control-D to exit)

service postgresql start
```

On some systems you might need to use an explicit path to the `postgres` executable, like `/usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/postgres`. Again, paths may vary based on version and distro.

Comment: `Alter user...` means for e.g., `alter user createdb`? That does not work, because postgres is a regular user now and cannot change roles...

Comment: @arthur Read the whole answer. See the bit about *single user mode* ? (I forced Stack Overflow to disable syntax highlighting, maybe that'll make it clearer).

Answer (score 1):

For Windows it is necessary to:

- create a local user called 'postgres'
- assign write rights for this user on the data folder
- stop the postgres service from services
- open a command prompt as postgres user (e.g. `runas /user:postgres cmd`)
- run postgres in single user mode

  ```
  "<PATHTOPOSTGRES>\postgres.exe" --single -D "<PATHTODATA>/data"
  ```

  where the relevant database is inferred from the username (postgres)
- Execute the necessary commands to get your user back to abnormal (super):

  ```
  backend> ALTER USER postgres SUPERUSER;
  backend> ALTER USER postgres LOGIN;
  backend> ALTER USER postgres REPLICATION;
  backend> ALTER USER postgres CREATEDB;
  backend> ALTER USER postgres CREATEROLE;
  backend> ALTER USER postgres INHERIT;
  backend> ALTER USER postgres CONNECTION LIMIT -1;
  backend> ALTER USER postgres VALID UNTIL 'infinity';
  backend> ALTER USER postgres UNENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'MYPASSWORD';
  ```
- Ctrl-C to exit
- start the postgres service from services

Note the 'bug' in earlier PGAdmin 16.1 related to opening a user's properties might have been the cause.

Comment: Since 9.x it is no longer necessary to create a dedicated Windows user to run Postgres.

Comment: If it is run by a user with administrative rights you will receive the following error message: "Execution of PostgreSQL by a user with administrative permissions is not permitted" - the name postgres simplifies the command line as the database utilised defaults to the user name.

Comment: If you use `pg_ctl` instead of `postgres` you can do all that using an administrator account as well, because `pg_ctl` will make sure that the additional privileges are "dropped" before running Postgres

Comment: If it was documented how pg_ctl could be run in single user mode that would be true.

Comment: Interesting. I wasn't aware that `pg_ctl` can not start Postgres in single user mode. `-o "--single"` does not seem to work.

Comment: It's mid 2021, and this answer helped me to retrieve the super user access!! Just want to know if we good to delete the user postgres now?