# How to restore everything (including "postgres" role) from pg_dumpall backup

Tags: postgresql, backup, restore, errors

I have a postgres 9.1 server running and I do backups with

```
pg_dumpall -c -f /nfs/backup/fulldump.sql
```

I'm testing restoring the backup to another server with

```
psql -f /nfs/backup/fulldump.sql
```

while running as user `postgres` and I get two errors

```
psql:/nfs/backup/fulldump.sql:27: ERROR:  current user cannot be dropped
psql:/nfs/backup/fulldump.sql:36: ERROR:  role "postgres" already exists
```

I understand that these are caused by commands

```
DROP ROLE postgres;
CREATE ROLE postgres;
```

in the backup dump.

**Is it possible to somehow restore the dump from `pg_dumpall -c` without having a single error?**

Comment: Searching around the web hints that *single user mode* (`postgres --single`) could be the correct answer. That can be started like described in answer http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/61784/29183 -- my dump takes around an hour to read in so I have to test it some later time...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ended up using grep for this:

```
egrep -v '^(CREATE|DROP) ROLE postgres;' dump.sql \
| psql -X -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 -1 ...
```

Comment: I think your regular expression should only match `DROP` and `CREATE`, not `ALTER`. Otherwise that should do the job.

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen good point, fixed.

Comment: I can't believe this is still a problem. Thanks for the grep.