# role "postgres" already exists when restoring cluster

Tags: postgresql

I backed up a server with

```
pg_dumpall.exe --file "backup.sql" --host "db" --port "5432" --username "user" --no-password --database "postgres" --verbose --clean
```

but when I tried to restore it on a new machine, I'm getting

```
postgres@home-lab-db-15:/home/ubuntu$ psql -f home-lab-db.sql postgres  -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1
SET
SET
SET
CREATE ROLE
ALTER ROLE
CREATE ROLE
ALTER ROLE
CREATE ROLE
ALTER ROLE
CREATE ROLE
ALTER ROLE
psql:home-lab-db.sql:24: ERROR:  role "postgres" already exists
```

I tried to drop the cluster and recreate it, but same error. I could not drop the postgres role or database `cannot drop role postgres because it is required by the database system`

[The docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/backup-dump.html#:%7E:text=psql%20%2Df%20dumpfile%20postgres) say

> if you are loading into an empty cluster then postgres should usually
> be used

so I'm confused at how to restore the backup.

Answer (score 0):

That error is expected and should be ignored. You cannot restore a `pg_dumpall` with `ON_ERROR_STOP` set.

Comment: thanks! I was coming from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20427689/psql-invalid-command-n-while-restore-sql and wanted to make sure I didn't have any errors causing that

Comment: It really sucks that errors are expected when restoring from a backup. How are we then expected to know which errors are expected and which are not?

Comment: See this answer for a way to modify the output so it doesn't generate errors: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/176562/57658

Comment: Nobody forces you to use `--clean`, and you could have used `--if-exists` to avoid the error. Don't blame your own mistakes on the software.